# C++11 how to extend a class template such as std::packaged_task

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to extend `std::packaged_task` to handle SEH exceptions but I can't get it to compile.

The following does not compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <windows.h>

template<class RET, class... ARGS>
class SafePackagedTask : public std::packaged_task<RET(ARGS...)>
{
public:
  template<class F>
  explicit SafePackagedTask(F && f)
    : std::packaged_task*(std::forward<F>(f))
  {
  }

  void operator()(ARGS... args)
  {
    __try
    {
      std::packaged_task*(std::forward<ARGS>(args));
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
      printf("SEH Exception 0x%08lX in SafePackagedTask!\n", GetExceptionCode());
    }
  }

};

int main()
{
    SafePackagedTask<int()> task([] {
      //int *a = nullptr; *a = 1; // generate SEH
      return 1;
    });
    std::future<int> fut = task.get_future();
    task();
    int rc = fut.get();
    printf("result: %d\n", rc);
}
```

The errors are:

```
source_file.cpp(9): error C2091: function returns function
source_file.cpp(37): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'SafePackagedTask<int (void)>' being compiled
source_file.cpp(38): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::future<_Ret>' to 'std::future<int>'
        with
        [
            _Ret=int (__cdecl *)(void)
        ]
source_file.cpp(38): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

See it on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/JQYUM90519).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work finally.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <windows.h>

template<class RET, class... ARGS>
class SafePackagedTask;

template<class RET, class... ARGS>
class SafePackagedTask<RET(ARGS...)> : public std::packaged_task<RET(ARGS...)>
{
public:
  template<class F>
  explicit SafePackagedTask(F && f)
    : std::packaged_task<RET(ARGS...)>(std::forward<F>(f))
  {
  }

  void operator()(ARGS... args)
  {
    __try
    {
      std::packaged_task<RET(ARGS...)>::operator()(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
      printf("SEH Exception 0x%08lX in SafePackagedTask!\n", GetExceptionCode());
      // ... print stack trace ...
    }
  }

};

int main()
{
    SafePackagedTask<int()> task([] {
      int *a = nullptr; *a = 1; // generate SEH
      return 1;
    });
    std::future<int> fut = task.get_future();
    try
    {
      task();
      int rc = fut.get();
      printf("result: %d\n", rc);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
      printf("error inside lambda: %s\n", e.what());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't do what I want in `/EHa` mode, because there is a `catch(...)` in `packaged_task` which catches everything and then re-throws in `future::get()`. The `__except` handler is never reached and the original stack trace is lost. So I abandoned this approach and wrap the underlying task itself:

```
template <typename F>
struct SafeTaskWrapper : F
{
  SafeTaskWrapper(F&& f) : F(std::move(f)) {}

  SafeTaskWrapper(SafeTaskWrapper&&) = default;
  SafeTaskWrapper& operator=(SafeTaskWrapper&&) = default;

  SafeTaskWrapper(const SafeTaskWrapper&) = default;
  SafeTaskWrapper& operator=(const SafeTaskWrapper&) = default;

  void operator()()
  {
    __try
    {
      F::operator()();
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
      printf("SEH Exception 0x%08lX in lambda!\n", GetExceptionCode());
      // ... print stack trace ...
      throw std::runtime_error("SEH Exception in lambda");
    }
  }
};

template <typename T>
auto make_safe_task(T&& t) -> SafeTaskWrapper<typename std::decay<T>::type>
{
  return std::move(t);
}

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> task(make_safe_task([] {
      //int *a = nullptr; *a = 1; // generate SEH
      return 1;
    }));
    std::future<int> fut = task.get_future();
    try
    {
      task();
      int rc = fut.get();
      printf("result: %d\n", rc);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
      printf("error inside lambda: %s\n", e.what());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to solve a problem which is already solved.
SEH exceptions can be handled like regular C++ standard exception by setting specific flag on VC++ (which you are clearly using)*

go to project -> C/C++ ->Code Generation -> set "Enable C++ exceptions" on "Yes with SEH exceptions".

now you can catch SEH exception with `catch(...)` clause:

```
try{

}catch(std::exception& e){}
catch(...) {/*your code here*}
```

Other than that, the best way to deal with SEH exception is not to create them at first place. not trying to read beyond you array boundries, checking for null pointers, using smart pointers when needed and carefully writing your classes to use RAII will probably eliminate 95% of exceptions in your code.

*basically, on windows all the C++ exceptions are subset of windows SEH and implemented as such.

Comment: We don't use this setting because we want more details about the SEH exceptions. RAII and all is of course nice for new development, but we have to work with a lot of legacy code unfortunately.

Comment: what is the problem getting the error code with `GetExceptionCode()` inside the `catch(...)` block?

Comment: `error C2707: '_exception_code': bad context for intrinsic function`. And besides, the stack trace is from ReThrow, not from the original location anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Many std classes are not intended to inherit from. One clue is if the destructor is not virtual, then, at the very least, the class is not intended to be used polymorphically.

Comment: I control fully the lifecycle of my class. Non-virtual destructor is not a problem.

Comment: @rustyx I have had colleagues who have extended other std library classes like vector or map, also doable albeit somewhat unorthodox.